# Can we get .proto message descriptor from C++ protobuf message wrapper?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Say we got C++ files but no .proto files. We have some message we want to get proto descriptors from it (like feature of C# protobuf-net when we can get proto description for annotated via protobuf-net class). Is there any api for obtaining such message description?

Answer (score 2):

No. Protocol buffer messages are not self-descriptive. That's part of their high-performance charm. If all you have are message and C++ code, you've got no choice but to read the C++ code and try to manually reconstruct the protobuf spec.